# Use of grateful

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, politeness, ellipsis

I have seen some people using 'grateful' in the beginning of a statement like.

> Grateful, if you can send me the details of the conference,

Can someone tell me if this usage is correct or not?

Comment: This does not sound correct to me as a native speaker of American English, but it might be used in some dialects.  More standard usage would be "**I would be** grateful if you could..." Where have you seen this used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would rather say no. This would sound better to me:

> I would be grateful if you could ...

Comment: ... or rather I should be grateful if you would...

Answer (score 2):

With the comma, it's incorrect.

Without the comma, it reads sort of okay to me, but it's very very informal. (note: *can* should really be *could*.)

> Grateful if you *could* send me the details of the conference.

This is short for the more correct sentence,

> **I would be** grateful if you could send me the details of the conference.

Comment: Given the extreme informality, I wouldn't even notice the can vs. could issue. Honestly, this is too informal even for a casual e-mail from me. I'd only consider for a text among friends, where it's a pain to type full sentences. +1.

Answer (score 0):

It's a stretch, but this might be admissible as part of a larger request. For example:

> I'd be satisfied if you filled out those forms for me. Grateful, even, if you submitted them yourself.

This is not grammatically ideal, so it'd only really work in an informal context. I doubt it applies to the instances you've seen, but I thought it would be worth mentioning for posterity.